# Travelling for Tourism with 1 year Business Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, germany, egyptian-citizens, malta

I am from Egypt and I have a multiple entry business visa Type C issued from the Malta embassy and I am planning to visit Germany first for a holiday, then heading to Malta for business. Days spent in both countries are roughly the same.

Is it ok that my purpose of travel to germany is tourism while my visa is for business purposes?  Is it ok to tell them that if they ask about my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the first usage of the visa, you should have told them your intended travel plan to both countries.

If the whole trip to both countries are within 90 days, that should be ok.

Business trip in Malta is the main purpose of the trip, so starting in Germany as a tourist and going on to Malta should also be ok.
(If asked, you intend to be 1 day longer in Malta)